# tortoise svn error: "this installation package is not supported by the processor type contact your product vendor"

Tags: windows, svn, installation, tortoisesvn

I tried loading the latest 32 bit version on one of my computers which did 
not have a previous version of Tortoise installed.
The download started and loaded installer.  Once it finished the following 
message appeared.

"This installation package is not supported by this processor type. 
Contact your product vendor."

I'm running 32 bit Windows 7 Ultimate.
My CPU is Intel(R) core(TM) i3 CPU @ 2.27 GHz.

What do I need to do to get Tortoise to install on this computer?
Is there a version that will work?

Comment: Intel(R) core(TM) i3 CPU @ 2.27 GHz

Comment: From [TortoiseSVN FAQ](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html), it says: `"This installation package is not supported by this processor type. Contact your product vendor." This means you are trying to install the 64-bit version of TortoiseSVN on a normal 32-bit operating system. You need to download and use the correct msi file for your OS. For normal 32-bit OS, make sure the msi file does not have an x64 in it.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you install the 32-bit installer, not the 64-bit one. They're separate links on the TSVN download page. It sounds to me you accidentally installed the 64-bit installer.